# Scipy.Minimize, how to share the same objects among objective function and constraints?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize-minimize

The objective function is

```
def obj(w):
    a = f(w)
    return g(a)
```

The constraint function is

```
def cons(w):
    a = f(w)
    return a - 1
```

The function f(w) in both obj(w) and cons(w) is calculation heavy. How to calculate f(w) just once for every guess of w please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can access variables from given function outside of it, using this mechanism:

```py
def f(a):
    out = a * a + 2
    f.inside = out
    return out
f.inside = None

print(f(1))
print(f.inside)
```

or using class.